# What are these index parameters in Robotium?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Many of the methods in the `Solo` class of Robotium take an `index` parameter, for example [`Solo.clickOnButton(int)`](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html#clickOnButton%28int%29). What is this index for? What is it indexing into? More importantly, how do I determine the index for a button or other view that I want to interact with?

Answer (score 2):

Many views cannot be reached in another way than by index. For instance dynamically loaded imageViews or imageButtons without R.id That's why there are indexes in robotium. Indexes are set from top left corner to bottom right corner - it means that for instance for layout with four buttons in square grid (2x2) indexes will be 0, 1 for first row and 2, 3 for second row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I have a complex layout with several TextViews and EditTexts but only one Button. What index should I use to get to the button?

Comment: That depends on used method. For clickOnButton just buttons, for clickOnView all views etc.